# New Column or Measure for NAICS ID based on first two numbers

Tags: filter, powerbi

Use first two digits of Column to give a name to a new column.

I have a list of companies and their NAICS ID. I would like to filter these into a pie chart but I don't want the 90000 different names (just the general ex. Agriculture or Mining). I want to utilize the first two digits in for the column to identify its general name. I am trying to use the DAX expression Switch to get this started. Is there a filter to do this within PowerBI?

I haven't started yet since I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a calculated column based off of the original NAICS code using the following:

```
FirstTwoDigitsOfNAICS :=
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    LEFT ( 'Table'[NAICSCode] ) = x, "Something",
    LEFT ( 'Table'[NAICSCode] ) = y, "Something Else"
)
```

This `DAX` will simply pull the first two characters from the entire code.

Comment: So how would I go from this new column and ordering it to spit out the name I am wanting. If the new column has 21, I want it to say "Mining" and if it's 11 it should call it "Agriculture"

Comment: Do you have a way of pulling those descriptions into a table with their primary codes i.e. first two digits? If so you could just join those two this new column.